# Counter sum filtered counts

Tags: python-3.x, counter

The result should sum over a counter like counter.total(), but only on certain elements in the counter. The elements should be filtered by their keys, I would imagine something like the following code existed:

`sum(counter_element.count() for counter_element in counter.elements() if counter_element.key() is good)`

How to achieve the correct result?

tried this with counter.elements(), counter.items() and counter.values() but no combination of functions did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum(count for (key, count) in counter.items() if key is good)
```

does the job. The main idea is that .items() returns the tuples and (key, count) then already holds the correct objects one can be interested in.